# Memory warning when using AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, xcode, avcapturesession

I use default AVCaptureSession to capture the camera view. Everything is working ok. But it runs for few seconds and log the message memory warning in the debugger and continues working for few seconds and then the application get terminates. This may be leakage of memory in the code i implement. But i have no idea, why this occur,
I addition to this i get a warning in the line as (sending "ViewController *const_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

```
[outputsetSampleBufferDelegate:selfqueue:queue];
```

.........................................................
Code implemented by me,

```
-(void)setupCaptureSession
{
NSError *error=nil;
AVCaptureSession *session =[[AVCaptureSessionalloc]init];
self.captureSession=session;


self.captureSession.sessionPreset=AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

AVCaptureDevice *device =[AVCaptureDevicedefaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

AVCaptureDeviceInput *Input=[AVCaptureDeviceInputdeviceInputWithDevice:deviceerror:&error];
if(!Input){
    }

    [[selfcaptureSession] addInput:Input];
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output =[[AVCaptureVideoDataOutputalloc]init];

    [[selfcaptureSession]addOutput:output];
dispatch_queue_t queue =dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [outputsetSampleBufferDelegate:selfqueue:queue];
dispatch_release(queue);

output.videoSettings =[NSDictionarydictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumbernumberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA],(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,nil];

AVCaptureConnection *connection =[output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    [connectionsetVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1,15)];

[sessionstartRunning];

    [selfsetSession:session];


}

-(UIImage *)imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
CVImageBufferRefimageBuffer =CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

void *baseAddress =CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

size_tbytesPerRow =CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
size_t width =CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height=CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

CGColorSpaceRefcolorSpace =CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress,width,height,8,bytesPerRow,colorSpace,kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGImageRefquartzImage =CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

UIImage *image =[UIImageimageWithCGImage:quartzImage];
CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

return image;
}
////////////////////

-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBufferfromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{


UIImage *image = [selfimageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
//Here i do my processing with image and display a count, Counter updates for few seconds and
  Log memory warning and then works again, Then application get terminates

}
-(void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session
{
self.captureSession=session;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using ARC?

Comment: I don't see any obvious leaks; perhaps it's in the code that does "processing"?

Comment: I remove my logic and checked it, But still the problem exist. Is it because of the warning (sending "ViewController *const_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id' in the line [outputsetSampleBufferDelegate:selfqueue:queue]; ?

Comment: In .h file, i used @interface ViewController :UIViewController { AVCaptureSession *captureSession; } and @property(strong,nonatomic)AVCaptureSession *captureSession;

Comment: The warning is saying that ViewController needs to be a AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, i.e. `@interface ViewController : UIViewController< AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate> { ... `